# NSArray of NSArray creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, magento

In my app I've to create a structure like this:

```
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        “product_id” => “1”,
        “qty” => 2
                "options" => array(         
                    optionId_1 => optionValue_1,
                    ...,
                    optionId_n => optionValue_n
                 )
```

I did this array of array so:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
       @"product_id" : productID,
       @"qty": self.qty
   };
NSArray *array2 = @[dict];
```

This array should work with a Magento store, when I run the app it shows me this message:

`error cart_product.add: SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I guess this problem, depends on how I create this array, but I'm not understanding what's wrong with this array, can you help me to fix it?

**UPDATE:**

The library I'm using to connect to Magento needs this structure:

```
[Magento call:@[@"customer.create", @{
     @"email": email,
     @"password": password,
     @"firstname": firstname,
     @"lastname": lastname,
     @"website_id": @1,
     @"store_id": Magento.service.storeID
}] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    Magento.service.customerID = responseObject;
    NSLog(@"signUp customerID = %@", Magento.service.customerID);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

I will use it to add a product into a cart if you take a look in [Magento SOAP API to add a product to cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) you can see that in `php`they add product by using an array of an array. I need to replicate the same structure.

Comment: Did you consider using a dictionary, as it seems to be more like a key/value based structure.

Comment: I need to do a stuff like this, because the library I'm using to connect to Magento needs the structure I will show you in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you put an `NSDictionary` in an  array, and after that you do it again. That's wrong. Do it like this:

```
NSDictionary *product1 = @{@"product_id" : productID, @"qty": self.qty, "options" : @{optionId_n : optionValue_n}};
NSDictionary *product2 = @{@"product_id" : productID, @"qty": self.qty, "options" : @{optionId_n : optionValue_n}};
NSArray *products = @[product1, product2];
```

Comment: It's not the same I did in my code? I will add only one product, so I guessed I've to create a single `NSDictionary` and then I need to put this `NSDictionary` in an `NSArray`

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work... It gives me the same error: `error SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`